# Unable to login to Domain Controller (windows server 2012 R2) after reverting VMWare snapshot

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2

We have a domain controller (windows server 2012 R2) and few replication servers. I had taken  a vmware snapshot of our DC few weeks back and today I had accidentally deleted few users and groups. So I reverted the DC to the last created snapshot. But now I am not able to login to the machine, even the administrator account doesn't seem to work. Any ideas how to fix it.

Comment: **Lesson Learned:** Don't restore a DC from a snapshot except in very narrow edge cases. Next time restore only the deleted AD object or objects. The specific method for doing so will depend on whether or not the AD Recycle Bin is enabled.

Answer (score 5):

***You should never, EVER use snapshots on domain controllers*** (*), otherwise a USN rollback (also known by other DCs as "you are bad and we don't want to talk with you anymore" and by sysadmins as "pain & suffering") will ensue.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2cae85b-41ac-497f-8cd1-5fbaa6740ffe(v=ws.10)
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2cae85b-41ac-497f-8cd1-5fbaa6740ffe(v=ws.10)#operational_considerations_for_virtualized_domain_controllers
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2cae85b-41ac-497f-8cd1-5fbaa6740ffe(v=ws.10)#usn_and_usn_rollback

The only way out of a USN rollback is to forcibly demote the non-replicating DC (or just reinstall it from scratch), clean up its metadata in Active Directory and then add it back to the domain and promote it again.

---

(*) Unless you *really* know what you are doing, and you take special care to do it properly; it can be done in some specific edge cases, but doing it carelessly is a sure way to kill a DC.

Comment: They *can* be used as a backup-of-last-resort, which is why I take snaps of my DCs. You're right, though - they can only be used in a very very small number of circumstances, and only if the entire rest of the domain infrastructure is forcibly torn down first.

Comment: This is an interesting conversation, As long as we are using a support Hypervisor and our PDC emulator is on a DC running 2012 or higher snapshots can be rolled back.             https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-ds/introduction-to-active-directory-domain-services--ad-ds--virtualization--level-100-

Comment: @MichaelBrown I know; but cloning a DC in a supported way is *quite* different from "I took a snapshot and reverted it back and now the DC isn't working anymore".

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting conversation. As long as we are using a supported Hypervisor, and as long as the PDC Emulator is on a DC running Server 2012 or higher we can create snapshots of DCs and we can roll them back without running in to USN issues and having to perform USN rollback

https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/identity/ad-ds/introduction-to-active-directory-domain-services--ad-ds--virtualization--level-100-

It may be that the version of VMware wasn't the correct version to support safe snapshotting of DCs.

If possible I would always enable the AD Recycle bin in order to restore accidentally deleted objects.

http://windowsitpro.com/active-directory/windows-server-2012-active-directory-recycle-bin

Taking snapshots of any VM is not a backup solution and should only be used to provide safeguards during upgrades / patching etc.

Do you have 2nd DC? can you login from there? if not then it might be a case of having to restore from backup.